# always display "result error "

Tags: php, html

when i run this code , always display on page "result error" or "no data avilable" Knowing that i add data in database : where is the wrong

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['update']))
            {
                    $data = getpost();
                    $search_Query = "SELECT * FROM employee WHERE user_id_assets = $data[0]";
                    $search_result = mysqli_query($conn , $search_Query);

                if($search_result)
                {
                    if( mysqli_num_rows($search_result))
                    {
                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)) {
                            $user_id_assets = $row['user_id_assets'];
                            $name_emp = $row['name_emp'];
                            $user_account = $row['user_account'];
                            $mail_account = $row['mail_account'];
                    }
                }else{
                    echo "no Data For This User ID";
                }       
            }else {
                echo "result Error";
            }
        } ?>
```

Comment: as seen from this code `$conn` is never defined?

Comment: seems this `$data[0]` is empty/null

Comment: $conn mighat have define in connection file, code is not completye...

Comment: Can you tell us what  $data = getpost();  returns ?

Comment: The problem will be in the result of the `getpost();` function, I expect. You should also read up on the risks of SQL injection!

Comment: Mr.Moiz This is function i mean :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This....

```
if(isset($_POST['update'])){
    $search_Query = 'SELECT * FROM employee WHERE user_id_assets = '.$_POST['user_id_assets'];
    $search_result = mysqli_query($conn , $search_Query) or mysqli_error($conn);

    if( mysqli_num_rows($search_result)){
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)) {
            $user_id_assets = $row['user_id_assets'];
            $name_emp = $row['name_emp'];
            $user_account = $row['user_account'];
            $mail_account = $row['mail_account'];
        }
    }else{
        echo "no Data For This User ID";
    }       
}
```

Comment: this is result :
Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\Website\process.php on line 60
no Data For This User ID

Comment: What  `$data = getpost()`  return? @RaedTattan

Comment: this is : 
 function getpost()
   {
    $post = array();
    $post[0] = $_POST['user_id_assets'];
    $post[1] = $_POST['name_emp'];
    $post[2] = $_POST['user_account'];
    $post[3] = $_POST['mail_account'];
    
   }

Comment: Please Check now. i have edited my answer. If still having error, There is error in `$_POST['user_id_assets']`

Comment: Amazing thaaaaaaaaaaank you dear

Comment: Please VoteUp my ansswer